# asp.net c# - MySQL Database data access problems once live

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, azure, connection

I have a problem where I cannot establish a connection with my MySQL Database. This only happens once I have published it to azure. It works fine locally.

On the live site, I get an exception every time the app tries to access the database.

The exception is:

**'db.Database.CurrentTransaction' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction {System.InvalidOperationException}**

```
public Tariff getDefaultTariff()
            {
                using (CompanyContext db = new CompanyContext())
                {
                    var res = from t in db.Tariffs
                              where t.systemcompanyid == GlobalVariables.CompanyId && t.name == "WebsiteCar"
                              select new Tariff
                              {
                                  name = t.name,
                                  km_rate = t.km_rate,
                                  time_rate = t.time_rate,
                                  flagfall = t.flagfall,
                                  id = t.id,
                                  systemcompanyid =t.systemcompanyid
                              };
                    return res.FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
```

My Db Context:

```
public class CompanyContext : DbContext
    {
        public CompanyContext() :  base("DbConString") { }

        public DbSet<Information> CompanyInformation { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Testimonial> Testimonials { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tariff> Tariffs { get; set; }
    }

[Table("tariff")]
    public class Tariff
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int systemcompanyid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int km_rate { get; set; }
        public int time_rate { get; set; }
        public int flagfall { get; set; }
    }
```

My Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConString" connectionString="Server=database.server.name;Database=dispatch_clients;uid=username;pwd=password;Convert Zero Datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: where is you MySQL database located? it must be a firwall issue between Azure server and you MySQL database machine. check and post the inner exception.

Comment: am guessing a firewall - connectivity issue here. pls check if mysql allows connections from azure

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was a firewall issue. Cheers for the help.